# Regge trajectories for higher spins

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, mesons

I have read that Regge theory did/does predict higher spin meson states, but that at higher spins the data becomes fuzzy for spins greater than 4. Why is this so?

In the book "[A Brief History of String Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ud64BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=regge%20trajectories%20spin%20greater%20than%204&source=bl&ots=2M8FU81tuv&sig=UobjdE3qun1-hyi3yuR71LCW5bA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KEg2VZmoE5C1sQSq24HQCA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=regge%20trajectories%20spin%20greater%20than%204&f=false)" there is a statement that seems to contradict what I said above, and refers to the success of Regge theory in predicting/explaining higher spin exchanges through Reggion and multi-Reggion exchanges.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where?

Comment: I do not remember now. It was in the slides of a talk I heard. There was some argument for why there's a resurgence of interest in glueball-like condensates and Regge theory.

Comment: From the book you linked: "In the case of baryons, one can find experimentally observed examples of spin J=10!" This is wrong. Baryons strictly have odd-half-integer spin only. According to the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-n-delta-resonances.pdf), the highest-spin baryon claimed to have been observed is J=15/2 and the highest-spin state with strong evidence behind it is J=11/2. For mesons the highest-spin state observed are J=6 (claimed) and J=5 (confirmed).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but the reason it's harder to observe high-spin resonances is because they tend to be very wide and decay to many-particle final states, both of which make analysis difficult.